# XCode doesn't run or even install project on device

Tags: xcode

I'm working on an iOS project in Xcode 6.1 (which includes an app extension, in case that's relevant). When I try to run the project on Xcode, however, it doesn't actually run the project -- it just says its finished running seconds after "Running [My target]" appears in the Xcode window's toolbar. A (2) in a grey circle appears to the left of the running text before the app "finishes," on successful runs there is usually a (3).

If I delete the app from the device and try to build and run it again, Xcode claims that it finished running *without ever installing it in the first place.*

In the console of my computer, I can see the following messages:

`10/23/14 9:56:33.045 AM Xcode[86586]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x11e05f000): no old package to delta against, falling back to old skool install
10/23/14 9:56:33.045 AM Xcode[86586]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x11e05f000): Blasting the bundle over to the device in an old skool way
10/23/14 9:56:37.949 AM Xcode[86586]: AMDErrorForMobileInstallationCallbackDict (thread 0x11c59e000): GOT AN ERROR 0xe800003a
10/23/14 9:56:37.956 AM Xcode[86586]: SZConduit: _MonitorResultDispatchFunction:140 (0x0x11c59e000): Got error from service: InstallationFailed
10/23/14 9:56:37.956 AM Xcode[86586]: _AMDeviceTransferAndInstall (thread 0x11e05f000): SZConduitSendPathWithPreflight failed: 0xe8008017
10/23/14 9:56:37.960 AM Xcode[86586]: writeDictToFile:1258 ==== Successfully wrote Manifest cache to /var/folders/yt/lbzml8ns3f5dfg7chpk14s2h0000gp/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.1/Xcode/af8b53723f8db55690c776f7ae336036/2031be7d6eb56fd1d8e5c85034f9500facb31def/ManifestCache.plist
10/23/14 9:56:37.961 AM Xcode[86586]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x11e05f000): returning 0xe8008017`

No one else working on this project has this issue. Occasionally I see an error message with something like "Can't run, a signed resource is missing or has been altered," but this is pretty rare.

I've tried reinstalling Xcode, this does nothing.

Deleting Derived data fixes the issue, but I have to delete it after every run or the problem reappears. This is pretty inconvenient, so I'm looking for a more permanent fix.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it eventually?

Comment: Yeah. Some script (Cocoapods copying bundle resources, I think) was modifying some part of the app after it was code signed, and this is apparently how Xcode lets you know that the code signing isn't working properly.